# Mysql в PHP - выбрать все записи за определенный день

Tags: php, mysql

Колонка типа date, необходимо получить все записи за дату, которая была 5 дней назад, какая это дата мы не знаем

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)` и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Описание [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

В PHP получить дату "5 дней назад" для передачи в запрос:

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days'))
```

Описание [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php).